# How can I take values from two strings and divide them from each others (JavaScript) (Win Rate calculator)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a scoreboard system to a table tennis club and I ran into a problem. I know how to add values to table with button, but I don't know how to divided wins with matches to get win rate and display it in different table cell.

[Picture about the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uiZ9.png)
[Picture when matches and wins are on the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5NG9.png)

[Adding values from buttons - System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc8Vt.png)

I would like that wins are divided by matches and displayed under the Win Rate table header. I tried to make wins and matches variables and divide them and then display the value, but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Please add codes as text in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in each onclick action:
"...;**document.getElementById('WINRATE_ELEMENT').innerHTML = document.getElementById('addov').innerHTML / document.getElementById('addoh').innerHTML * 100**"

Instead of "WINRATE_ELEMENT" put the ID of Win Rate element.

For example:

```
<td><button class="addbutton" onclick="document.getElementById('addoh').innerHTML++;document.getElementById('WINRATE_ELEMENT').innerHTML = document.getElementById('addov').innerHTML / document.getElementById('addoh').innerHTML * 100">Add match</button></td>
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your answer. It worked out perfectly! Thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem. But better to use functions and make it in separate JS file.